# Combine two resultset from different table

Tags: java, mysql

My Requirement is to display some of the columns in one table and some of the columns in another table in an html table. Though it has same coloumn id , value will be different.  So, I cannot match this two. My query is as follows:

```
      SELECT time_stamp,queryresultset FROM table1 d WHERE dID = 'CP009'
      AND d.time_stamp >'2011-05-01 00:00:00' AND d.time_stamp < '2011-05-01 05:00:00'
      order by time_stamp
      UNION ALL
      SELECT time_stamp,cpuutil FROM table2 h WHERE hID='HS002'
      AND h.time_stamp >'2011-05-01 00:00:00' AND h.time_stamp < '2011-05-01 05:00:00'
      order by time_stamp
```

So, the time_stampe here I'm getting will vary just in milliseconds for both the table. But, I want it in one resultset. Though the time value varies in millisecones between the table, the number of rows will be equal. So, I have to bring this in a single resultset. I don't know whether it is possible to handle in sql query. Or I may have to try in java coding? Please guide me. Following is my sample html table.

```
          ----------------------------------------------------
           Time_stamp           Cpuutil        Queryresultset
          ----------------------------------------------------
           2011-03-09 12:00:00    2.3            9.8
           2011-03-09 12:15:00    5.3            4.5
           2011-03-09 12:30:00    4.3            9.3
           2011-03-09 12:45:00    2.3            9.2
```

Comment: What do You mean by _bring this in a single resultset_? Do You want to do sth like a `JOIN` on the `time_stamp` column, and the values aren't exacly equal, but the're very close so the diffrerence is in milliseconds and You'd like to round it up somewhow to join the results on that rounded value?

Comment: Can You rely on `ORDER BY time_stamp` returning the rows from both tables in valid sequence? What I mean is if it's true that despite the `time_stamp` values differ in milliseconds, the order of the rows in both tables still matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid, I have difficulties with understanding your question, but it seems to me, you are looking for something as:

`SELECT table1.time_stamp t1, table1.queryresultset, table2.time_stamp t2, table2.cpuutil`

`FROM table1 , table2`

`WHERE ABS(t1-t2)<100`

```
  AND t1 >'2011-05-01 00:00:00' 

  AND t1 < '2011-05-01 05:00:00'
```

`ORDER by t1`

Another posibility:

```
        `SELECT column list
        FROM table1
                    INNER JOIN table2
                    ON table1.col1=table2.col2
        WHERE criteria
        ORDER BY column list `
```

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a database conception mistake. If your two tables are linked logically, they should have a physical connector. If you can refactor your database model, the best solution is to add a table `table0` holding the common factors between the two tables (or just an autoincrement id), and then to add an external key to `table1` and `table2`. You need to insert a row into `table0` first, then to insert a row into `table1` and one into `table2` using `table0`'s key as an external key.

---

If you can't refactor the tables, that's too bad. Anyway, the easiest way to do what you want is to write java code:

- Open resultset1 from table 1
- Open resultset2 from table 2
- While resultset1 is not empty

  - fetch row1 from resultset1
  - fetch row2 from resultset2
  - generate html
- Close resultsets
- Done!

But this way is wrong and you will get problems as you advance further in your project.

Comment: But, If I get as different resultset, I cannot get both the values in the same row of html table. Using scriptlet, I'm creating the rwos dynamically. And the resultset values are stored in java object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses. So I found out the query. It's working now.

```
   SELECT a.cpuutil,a.hostid,a.time_stamp, b.queryresultset, b.time_stamp AS tm 
   FROM table1 a, table2 b 
   WHERE a.hID = 'hs002' AND b.dID='cp011' 
   AND SUBSTR(a.time_Stamp,1,15) = SUBSTR(b.time_stamp,1,15) 
   AND a.time_stamp > '2011-05-10 00:00:00'
   AND a.time_stamp < '2011-05-10 14:00:00'
```

Comment: Hello. You are absolutely right. The same answer as mine. But mine was earlier. So, would you be so kind and sign it as a correct answer, please?